# Session is not working in express js

Tags: node.js, express, session, session-cookies

I'm creating login application using express-session. When I login to the application via post request the the cookie will created,but Session is not working for me.

Server.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
  key: 'user_sid',
  secret: 'somerandonstuffs',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    expires: 600000
  }
}));
var sessionChecker = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
    res.redirect('/');;
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.session.user)
  if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
    result = { "message": "loggedinwithsession" };
    res.send(result);
  } else {
    var data = req.body;
    var responseData = {};
    console.log(data);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    controller.cont.login(data.email, data.password).then(result => {
      res.send(result),
        req.session.user = result;
    }
    ).catch(result => res.send(result))
  }
})
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `session`? Why not `JWT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the result data before the sessions can be set.

```
controller.cont.login(data.email, data.password).then(result => {
    res.send(result), //wrong
    req.session.user = result;
}).catch(result => res.send(result))
```

You should do like this.

```
controller.cont.login(data.email, data.password).then(result => {
    console.log("setting session"); //for debugging
    req.session.user = result; // first set session
    res.send(result);          // then send result
}).catch(result => res.send(result))
```

Here is a minimal version.

```
app.all('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.session)
    res.send("welcome")
})
app.get('/set', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.session)
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    req.session.data = "test session value"
    res.send("test")
})
```

Comment: check with the updated minimal version.
First hit /set then hit / check if the session values are printed

Comment: i have added a console.log for debugging, check if that prints out.